# The core maths API

Tags: objective-c, libraries

On the Apple developer reference here (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/) site I am looking for the api for the core set of maths functions available (and how they might be called), i.e. just stuff like sin, cos, pow(a,b) etc etc.

I can't find the page in the documentation where this is all listed.

Can someone help. Apologies if this is a dumb question.

Comment: I am surviving using wikipedia c99 definitions but the apple docs layout is very user friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I have received on this is from Cyrille. I do not know how to attribute it and so I have pasted it here. Perhaps a moderator could improve the situation.

You could try compiling some documentation with AppleDoc. – Cyrille Sep 15 at 22:42

Answer (score 0):

These are just the good old C math functions.

Comment: Thank you. I did realise that. As i said in my comment, I am trying to find where Apple documents them. The wikipedia math.h describes the cpp functions and I got a right old flaming the other day fro suggesting that Objective-C was substantially the same as Cpp. I am no expert but I was hoping to be pointed to some definitive API for the Objective C superset of maths fucntions.

Comment: @nerak99: `math.h` is the C (not C++) header file for math functions. You can use those in Objective-C programs without any problems.

Comment: The math.h in wikipedia says exactly what you say but the links that you follow then refer to cpp(!). In the cases I am interested in this may be quite important because the algorithms used may be sensitive to input data. Thats why I am looking for good documentation.

Comment: You could try compiling some documentation with AppleDoc.